# Apache Kafka consumer consumes messages with "partition" option, but not with "group" option

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am running a plain Apache Kafka server (version 3.4.1) which I would like to connect to a Telegraf consumer. The Telegraf `[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]` plugin has the option to consume by Kafka "group". When staring Telegraf, I get an error message

```
[inputs.kafka_consumer] Error in plugin: consume: kafka server: Request was for a consumer group that is not coordinated by this broker
```

Hence, I started to investigate my setup by using the Kafka console tools and found that when executing

```
 ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server myserver:9092 --topic test --partition 0
```

and sending messages via `kafka-console-producer.sh`, these messages pop up in the console "consumer" window as expected.

In contrast to this, when I run

```
 ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server myserver:9092 --topic test --group my-group
```

nothing happens in the "consumer" window. Furthermore, the command

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server myserver:9092 --list
```

yields nothing.

What do I have to do to cause the consumer with the "group" option to "see" the messages produced to the topic "test"? Ultimately, how can I solve the Telegraf error?

Update: it would be great if you provide a set of Kafka console commands which reliably produces and consumes messages to a consumer group.

Comment: 1) Using `--partition 0` does not use consumer groups, which is why listing does nothing. 2) Telegraf should work, but the error seems to suggest the group needs to be created ahead of time

Comment: @OneCricketeer according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61770993/how-to-create-a-new-consumer-group-in-kafka I understood that consumer groups are not explicitly created, but get created on the fly when the consumer establishes it's connection. Or am I wrong? In addition to that I did not find a way to create a user group separated from the consumer call...

Comment: They only get created when not using partition assignment

Comment: So in my second case Kafka should create groups, right? But I don‘t see any when executing ‚Kafka-consumer-groups‘

Comment: You'll only be able to describe the group while the consumer group is active, otherwise, the output will say there's no active consumers

Answer (score 0):

I can't really comment on why Telegraf is not working, however....

If you have a large number of partitions in your topic, it can take a really long while before you start seeing messages on the console.

So, using the partition id is the right approach. But just need to be patient at the command-line.

Out of interest, how long did you wait for the output from console consumer ?

If you need to know the partition id, you will need to use a custom program to compute it based on the key. (You could have a look at the murmur2 source code on the Kafka github repository and try to create a simple command line tool to compute the partition id using the key).

However, using --group option will only set the consumer group id of your instance of the kafka-console-consumer.sh. If you have other consumers that are part of this consumer group, then I believe some rebalancing should occur as some partitions will get moved to your kafka-console-consumer.sh client.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I do not have a large number of partitions. Actually I am running a littele toy instance of Kafka with one topic and three partitions. Concerning latency between producing and consuming: the delay is negligible, not noticable.